# Login fails on Subtext

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, blogs, subtext

I have just downloaded subtext 2.5 source code and manage to run it on Visual Studio dev server. The problem is that whenever I try to navigate to admin/.. it redirects me to login page and it's not accepting default login credentials that are, I suppose, `haacked` and `password` respectively. But I was unable to login to the site.

Subtext_Host table of db contains following entry:

```
   userid= Haacked, password= sIHb6F4ew//D1OfQInQAzQ==  salt=KrPog8xD4kKBwW35zBxxCA==   email=haacked@gmail.com datecreatedutc = 2011-06-11 21:37:29.533
```

I also tried resetting the password as described [here](http://subtextproject.com/Installing-and-Upgrading.ashx) (scroll to bottom) but to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The password you have reset is the Hostadmin password, accessible via `http://<yoururl>/hostadmin/default.aspx` by logging in there you should be able to reset the password for the particular blog you are interested in.

Comment: thank you very much. can u refer some link where i can find some documentation of subtext. e.g what's the purpose of Admin section and how it differs from hostadmin and similar issues?